# SMS Block and Allow issue in android 4.4 (kitkat) version

Tags: android, sms

We have sms blocking app live on google play. It blocks sms if satisfies any blocking condition else we allow that sms to native inbox. It is working good on all version except android 4.4 (Kitkat). We were trying to implement new sms apis available for 4.4 and got success in blocking sms after putting that app as a default sms app. But the problem is if that sms doesn't satisfies any sms blocking condition then we don't have any option to move that sms into native inbox.

Other option we have is to create total sms app with all sms related features. But it is useless in our case.

So is there any other option available in new android kit kat where I can transfer sms to other sms apps if I don't want to block that sms?

Please help me.. Getting lots of 1 star comments from kitkat users for this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The Telephony content provider (the "SMS Provider") allows apps to read and write SMS and MMS messages on the device. It includes tables for SMS and MMS messages received, drafted, sent, pending, and more.
>
> Beginning with Android 4.4, the system settings allow users to select a "default SMS app." Once selected, only the default SMS app is able to write to the SMS Provider and only the default SMS app receives the SMS_DELIVER_ACTION broadcast when the user receives an SMS or the WAP_PUSH_DELIVER_ACTION broadcast when the user receives an MMS. The default SMS app is responsible for writing details to the SMS Provider when it receives or sends a new message.
>
> Other apps that are not selected as the default SMS app can only read the SMS Provider, but may also be notified when a new SMS arrives by listening for the SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION broadcast, which is a non-abortable broadcast that may be delivered to multiple apps. This broadcast is intended for apps that---while not selected as the default SMS app---need to read special incoming messages such as to perform phone number verification.
>
> For more information, read the blog post, [Getting Your SMS Apps Ready for KitKat](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html).

Sample manifest from android blog is;

```
<manifest>
    ...
    <application>
        <!-- BroadcastReceiver that listens for incoming SMS messages -->
        <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver"
                android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- BroadcastReceiver that listens for incoming MMS messages -->
        <receiver android:name=".MmsReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- Activity that allows the user to send new SMS/MMS messages -->
        <activity android:name=".ComposeSmsActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />                
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Service that delivers messages from the phone "quick response" -->
        <service android:name=".HeadlessSmsSendService"
                 android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE"
                 android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```