# Forward messages from custom Default SMS Application to "native" provider SMS Application

Tags: android, sms, uri, android-4.4-kitkat, android-contentresolver

Ok so I know that this is a security/usability feature implemented in Android 4.4+, and addressed on numerous occasion here on SO. The issue that I am having is that I don't want to create a text messaging application. In fact, `the only use of texting in my application is so that an outside admin can ping the phone with a text from a specific number, and have a simple "Running" message returned if the application is running.` -Note, I am able to detect the reception of a message as well as send messages, I just can't delete the message from the inbox.

There is no functionality issue in leaving the messages in the inbox, but it would get annoying for the user after a while and the admins seem to like being able to ping their users in a background-type manner. So long story short, because

```
int deletedRows = context.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id), "date=?",
             new String[] { c.getString(4) });  
if(deletedRows > 0) Log.d(TAG, "Delete success...");
else Log.d(TAG, "Delete error...");
```

Is always prompting `Delete error...` in my log, because the delete doesn't work as expected, I need to figure out a new way of doing things.

I have read [SMS for KitKat](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/kitkat.html#44-sms-provider), [Getting SMS Apps Ready for KitKat](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html), and [A Similar SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280857/sms-block-and-allow-issue-in-android-4-4-kitkat-version) (which has an accepted answer), but I seem to be missing something. The issue is that I don't want to have to take control over receiving, displaying, sending, the handling in general of all of the text messages. I just want to be able to delete a specific message from a specific user.

So it seems the best solution is the use my application as the Default SMS Application, delete the individual message I need, and forward all other messages to my "native" provider SMS application. I don't exactly know how to do this (my Uri/parsing skills are not so great), it seems to me that it would be something like

```
Log.d(TAG, "Values to send: " + address + " / " + body);
ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
content.put("address", address);
content.put("body", body);
// continue for date, person, etc.
context.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id), content);
```

But, though my log shows the correct values, I never get sent a message. What am I missing (or is there a better way of going about this)?

Comment: did you manage in the end ? I am looking into doing this myself....

Comment: I was never able to successfully keep the message from getting to the inbox @TiGer

Comment: This is precisely the scenario I'm in. Did you ever come up with something or did they just learn to live with the messages being in the inbox? I have more control over our phones so I may literally just write an SMS app that passes intents to my main app and eats the messages but I would love to not do that. (Today's agenda: locate an open source SMS project for KitKat...)

Comment: @JamieB very sorry for the drastically delayed response. I was unable to find a solution to this problem unfortunately. Rather frustrating to say the least, but I hope you have had better luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is impossible for the current version of Android (7 and earlier). You need next steps to forward messages to previous default sms app:

1. Write you own SMS broadcast receiver
2. Register the SMS broadcast receiver in the manifest file (with android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER intent filter)
3. Get android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS permission to allow to handle SMS messages.
4. Handle SMS intent in onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) handler of your broadcast receiver.
5. Forward received intent to previous sms app.

   5.a To forward intent to specified app you need to call intent.setClassName("previous app package name", "previous app receiver class name")

   **5.b You must to have android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS to broadcast sms intents from your custom app. But (Surprise!!!) this permission can only granted to system apps.**